# How do you manage Internet Explorer using IEAK and Group Policy?

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer

We've always used "Internet Explorer Maintenance" (IEM) in Group Policies to manage Internet Explorer settings.  Apparently since IE 10, [we need to use Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK) to manage it.](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn338129.aspx)

Specifically, I'm looking to add favorites to the links bar via Group Policy, which I've previously been able to achieve using IEM.  We're now trying out Internet Explorer 10 and 11 on Windows 7 PCs and have found that the "URLs/Favorites and Links" section of IEM is no longer working for these versions of IE.

I've read that IEAK is the current way that Microsoft recommends administrators manage IE preferences, etc (including adding favorites to IE), but having run through the Internet Explorer Customization Wizard and generated an INSTALL.INS file, I'm non the wiser how to apply this to our PCs via Group Policy.

Is there a better way of distributing/updating favorites across our PCs?  Or if you agree with Microsoft that IEAK is the way forward, how do I implement this properly?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this isn't exactly the answer I thought I wanted, but it allows me to add links to favourites without having to mess with IEAK.  I stumbled across the answer [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/315655-how-can-i-add-urls-to-the-favorites-bar-in-ie10-via-gpo-rsat-windows-8-2012).

> User configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Shortcuts: New Shortcut
>
> Action: Replace
>
> Name: %USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links\Name of Favourite
>
> Target Type: URL
>
> Location: <Specify full path>
>
> Target URL: http://www.urloffavourite.com/
>
> Common tab: CHECKED - Remove this item when it is no longer applied

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but I didn't have the time earlier, glad you worked it out. It's how we're doing it and it works just fine :)

Comment: Hi pauska, good to know I've come to the same conclusion as others.  Thanks for the feedback.